# Extracting data categorized

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some data, in this instance, some codes entered by some IPs. 
Now, due to codes being submitted at different times, I want to classify the codes by the IP.
For example:

`row1: X IP, Y Code; row2: Y IP, Z Code; row3: X IP, Y2 Code`

How can I extract all the codes that were entered by X IP then by Y IP, and so on till there are no IPs left? Like a foreach loop where it iterates through all IPs till there's no more?

Finally, I expect the data to be:

```
IP X: Y, Y2 codes

IP Y: Z code(s)
```

Comment: GROUP BY ? Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as it is hard to make a suggestion/answer without knowing example data and or expected results.

Comment: GROUP BY what? The idea is how to make the GROUP BY statement iterate on each and every IP?

Comment: *"GROUP BY what? The idea is how to make the GROUP BY statement iterate on each and every IP? "* See mine rest of the comment the GROUP BY was a guess, as GROUP BY normally scans the complete table/index and "categorize"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MySql provides you `group_concat()` for this.

In case i got your question right, you should try something like this:

```sql
SELECT IP, group_concat(Code)
FROM table_with_some_data
GROUP BY IP;
```